# C++ interface multiple inheritance with same method

Tags: c++, interface, multiple-inheritance

I need to inherit from two interfaces which both have the same method which in both cases should perform exactly the same thing. Is this code correct or not? I need this for some kind of proxy class. Thanks for answers.

```
class InnerInterface {
    virtual int getID() const = 0;
    //...
};
class OuterInterface {
    virtual int getID() const = 0;
    //...
};
class Foo : public InnerInterface, public OuterInterface {
    virtual int getID() const;
    //all abstract methods
};
```

Comment: The methods should be `virtual`, right?

Comment: Nice question - from the title I was expecting a nice simple diamond inheritance (so use virtual inheritance) thing, but with this I'm not sure. You could certainly use scope resolution to override the two inherited methods with the same name separately, but that means duplicate code, so this is interesting.

Comment: Yeas. There is a lot of diamond problems on this forum but I have not found anything like this even in the books. So I have asked the question.

Comment: `IUnknown::QueryInterface` from the COM world is quite like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. The single getID() method can override both virtual methods.

Comment: Could you provide some information about this and what the outcome would be? Thanks!